# i know password allthought i not get super user authentication

Tags: 12.04

I enter the known password  , but it does not permit me and gives below error in the display
`su : Authentication failure.`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly use `su`, as you can not use the root password (which is normally not set).
Use `sudo su` instead, with your own password.

For More Info , read [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: @Mikpatel Glad to help - you should "accept"  the answer with the checkmark if it solved the problem, and maybe upvote it. (Otherwise it will technically stay unanswered forever)